# Why is my Azure application asking for admin consetment although i do not request for admin scopes?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I am developing a web application that allow users from any azure organization to give my application reading rights on their OneDrive using windows Graph-Api (scope: File.Read.All)

I registered a multi-tenants application in the azure portal and i configured the application like it is explained in the documentation

I need to Allow a user from other azure organisations to make a consentment for my application to read files content, but in my case i get a "Need admin aproval" after sending Authentication Code URL (tested with a user from another azure organization)

AuthenticationCode:`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YYY&scope=user.read files.read.all offline_access&state=ZZZ`

[What a user get after authetification to his Office-365 account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFLkX.png)

I know that there is other applications who do not have this issue, for exemple the application app.diagrams.net need only user consentment and not admin consentment even if it ask for read write scopes

diagrams.net AuthenticationCode:`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=b5ff67d6-3155-4fca-965a-59a3655c4476&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.diagrams.net%2Fmicrosoft&scope=user.read files.readwrite.all offline_access&state=cId%3Db5ff67d6-3155-4fca-965a-59a3655c4476`

[What a user get with diagram application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho5Jy.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of any particular scope. The answer to your question is discussed under "application provisioning" in Azure AD (AAD) terms. Put simply, an AAD application needs to be "provisioned" into an AAD tenant, and a tenant admin can choose whether users can initiate this by themselves or not. Here, it seems this is not allowed.

In more detail, when you create an AAD application, you create 2 objects: a representation of the application, and a "Service Principal" that handles access to that application. When you offer your AAD app to other tenants/organizations, they need their own service principal object to be able to access your application, and this happens through admin consent i.e. provisioning.

In general, there are 2 articles that you should take a look:

[How and why applications are added to Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-applications-are-added)

[How to: Sign in any Azure Active Directory user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)

And these code samples should clarify the process:

[Developing a Multi-tenant (SaaS) application with the Microsoft Identity Platform](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnet-webapi-multitenant)

[Protect a multi-tenant SaaS web application that calls Microsoft Graph using Azure AD & OpenID Connect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant)

**EDIT:** Correction: tenant admins can choose or not whether users are allowed to initiate app provisioning. Credits: @jasonJohnston.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. Admins can turn off users' ability to consent to multi-tenant apps, which is likely the case here. In that case, the admin has to do the consent (to provision the service principals). If the admins don't turn this off, then any user from the org can do so.

Comment: @JasonJohnston my apologies, indeed you're right: this is now optional. I'll edit the answer.